# (Access-Control-Allow-Origin - CORS issue when fetching data from 2 URL for promises

Tags: angularjs, promise, cors, jsonp

So I have promises in AngularJS which fetch data from 2 URLs.

```
promises.push(loadingJson('example.com/1.json'));
promises.push(loadingJson('example.com/2.json'));

$q.all(promises).then(function(resultList){ 
}, function(errList){
});
```

After running the page (using Promises) in web server, it gives error "Origin 'www.abc' not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." and "XMLHttpRequest cannot load '1.json' and '2.json' due to access control checks".

For Jquery GET method I can use JSONP to solve the error. 
But is there a way that can solve it in angularJS promises?

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS is client sided. You can solve your problem server sided here and leave your AngularJS code untouched. You can use cors.

It depends on your web server. For example if you are using express try this package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

and then set it correctly and it will work. (Perhaps you are trying to run server and client on the same host? it is quite a common scenario)

Comment: Thanks. I'm using digital ocean to host the web server, and I think is apache  for the database. trying to google how to resolve this ..